# How to load images from URL with a TensorFlow 2 dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I want to use a TensorFlow 2 dataset object to feed images to a CNN. My images are located on AWS S3, but I will use images from Wikipedia in my example (the problem is the same).

```py
image_urls = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Matterhorn_from_Domh%C3%BCtte_-_2.jpg',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Matterhorn_from_Klein_Matterhorn.jpg',
]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_urls)

def read_image_from_url(url):
    img_array = None
    with urlopen(url) as request:
        img_array = np.asarray(bytearray(request.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  #as RGB image (cv2 is BGR by default)
```

When I test my function with one element of the dataset, it works:

```py
url = next(iter(dataset)).numpy().decode('utf-8')
img = read_image_from_url(url)
plt.imshow(img)
```

But when I map my function to the dataset to create a new dataset serving the images, it fails:

```py
dataset_images = dataset.map(lambda x: read_image_from_url(x.numpy().decode('utf-8')))

AttributeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-6-e8eb89833196>:2 None  *
        map_func=lambda x: read_image_from_url(x.numpy().decode('utf-8')),

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Obviously, the dataset provides a different dtype when iterated with `next` or with `map`. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well this was way harder than it needs to be:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
import cv2
from urllib.request import urlopen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image_urls = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Matterhorn_from_Domh%C3%BCtte_-_2.jpg',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Matterhorn_from_Klein_Matterhorn.jpg',
]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_urls)

def get(url):
    with urlopen(str(url.numpy().decode("utf-8"))) as request:
        img_array = np.asarray(bytearray(request.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

def read_image_from_url(url):
    return tf.py_function(get, [url], tf.uint8)


dataset_images = dataset.map(lambda x: read_image_from_url(x))

for d in dataset_images:
  print(d)
```

Why did the first one work and then failed in the `tf.Dataset`? Well `tf.Dataset` is defined in `graph mode` not in `eager mode` like the first one. Graph mode is faster, and `tf.Dataset` is optimized for speed, so it makes sense. You can't do `.numpy()`, in graph mode, as everything should be defined in `tensorflow` ops. `py_func` wraps a python function in an `tf.Operation` that is executed in `eager mode`, which is just what we needed.

Note: I tried `tf.keras.utils.get_file()`, but I ran into similar issues as you are describing here. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. py_function is indeed the solution. I am wondering what's the difference between tf.py_function and the new TF2 decorator @tf.function....

Comment: `tf.py_function` wraps everything defined and executes it eagerly,  and `@tf.function` converts python code to a tensorflow graph, so it can be run in parrallel on the GPU. So they are (a bit) inverse, tf.py_function converts fast (or already slow) code to slow eager execution, `@tf.function` converts slow eager code to fast graph mode, but it cannot convert arbitrary code. check out `ŧf.autograph` what can be converted.